# Center a view inside viewcontroller in iOS Playground app

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm currently building a swift playground book. Is it possible to center a view inside a view controller while running on an iPad ?

Here's my `loadView` function of my view controller:

```
override public func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667)
    self.view = view

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 375)
    let newView = UIView(frame: frame)
    view.addSubview(newView)
}
```

How can I center the `newView`in the view of the view controller?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it using Autolayout:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 375)
let newView = UIView(frame: frame)
view.addSubview(newView)
newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    newView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    newView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.heightAnchor),
])
newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

**UPDATE**

Playground code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667)
        self.view = view

        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 375)
        let newView = UIView(frame: frame)
        newView.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(newView)

        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            // need to define its size too
            newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 375),
            newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
            ])
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: It does not work :/ The view disappear. I guess it's set outside of the visible area?

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers try now

Comment: Still invisible :/

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers did you add something to the view? by default, it has `.clear` background color, so with just the code that you showed you would not be able to see it.. if that the case, change its color to e.g., red, as I did in updated answer

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers can you share the whole code that you use?

Comment: Here's a pastebin of a simplified version of the code: https://pastebin.com/teGzTCc0

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers sorry, got to it only this late.. check the updated answer..

Comment: Thanks it's work :) I just updated: newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor) to newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 375),

Answer (score 2):

### View Controller Lifecycle - slight difference between an Xcode *Playground* and an Xcode *Project*...

In this Xcode playground, notice the view controller's `view` bounds don't yet match the simulator size in `viewDidLoad`(). The simulator seems to default to iPad size but then display at iPhone size. In an Xcode *project* however, this isn't the case — you *can* get the current simulator bounds in `viewDidLoad()`.

In either case, a better place to position your subviews is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.
[image]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var yellowView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yellowView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        yellowView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250)
        view.addSubview(yellowView)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        yellowView.center =  CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height / 2)
    }
}

let vc = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
newView.center = self.view.center
```

Comment: Well it's work in xCode on mac but it doesn't on the playground app on iPad

Comment: Hmmmm... I’ll do some digging after Church

Comment: Here's a pastebin of a simplified version of the code: https://pastebin.com/teGzTCc0

Comment: I retry your code and it's work. But it's doesn't work in my original playground I will check my code

Comment: it's only work on xCode on mac but not on swift playground

Comment: Oh on you iPad Pro playground is what you’ve been saying. Idk that’s probably a glitch that Apple needs to address.